# awk help needed

Tags: awk

I have a file with the contents as such:

item1 item2   <--- can be 1 or more and up to probably 10+

date1

date2

item2 item3 item4     <-- 1 or more as well

date3

date4

.

.

.

And this data needs to be formatted into:

item1 date1 date2

item2 date1 date2

item2 date3 date4

item3 date3 date4

item4 date3 date4

.

.

.

I am really novice in awk so I thought I could ask in here. This is my first question in stackoverflow so please let me know what other kind of info I should provide? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should edit your question and show us the code you've already tried.

Comment: Thought of that @Catcall but well the thing is I've been trying for more than a day and could not come up with anything... tried associative arrays but just cldn't apply to this problem...

Comment: When you don't post code, it doesn't look like you want help with your code. It looks like you want someone else to do your work for you. The best people here generally won't do your work for you.

Comment: post some actual items and actual dates rather than just the words "item" and "date" so we can at least see what format distinguishes dates from items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   #awk -f myawk.sh temp.txt
   BEGIN { print "Start"}
   /item/ {for(i=1; i<=b; i++){ print a[i]"----"d }}
   /item/ {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ a[i] = $i; b=i;d=""}}
   /date/ {d = d" "$0;}
   END {for(i=1; i<=b; i++){ print a[i]"----"d } print "Process Complete"}
```

Output

```
Start
item1---- date1 date2
item2---- date1 date2
item2---- date3 date4
item3---- date3 date4
item4---- date3 date4
End
```

Comment: Thanks @user19340357! Let me try to incorporate this into my small script. :)